# Problems transforming polygon projections inside Shiny app

Tags: r, leaflet, coordinate-system, shiny

I've just recently started attempting to build mapping apps with `leaflet` and `shiny` in R. I'm currently stumped by an issue with projecting polygons inside `shiny`.

[Here is the shapefile to reproduce my code](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9yl2rteoud67t3n/AACaoApcyt95OC13IfoK8QSqa?dl=0), and here's the stripped down code:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet) #MUST INSTALL DEVELOPMENT VERSION WITH:  devtools::install_github('rstudio/leaflet')
library(sp)
library(rgeos)
library(rgdal)


#pull in full rock country shapefile, set WGS84 CRS
countries <- readOGR("D:/NaturalEarth/HIF", layer = "ctry_hif", 
                     stringsAsFactors = F, encoding = "UTF-8")
countries <- spTransform(countries, CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))

#run shiny app
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(leafletOutput('myMap', width = "80%", height = 500),
                 absolutePanel(width = "20%", top = 10, right = 5, 
                               selectInput(inputId = "location",
                                           label = "Country", 
                                           choices = c("", countries@data$sovereignt), 
                                           selected = "")
                 )
  ),     #END UI

  server <- function(input, output, session) {

    #observe click event; zooms to administrative units for the country that is clicked on
    observeEvent(input$location, {

      #subset countries shapefile by dropdown selection country
      selected <- countries[countries@data$sovereignt == input$location,]

      # selected <- spTransform(selected, CRS("+proj=moll +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"))
      # selected <- gBuffer(selected, width = -.2)
      # selected <- spTransform(selected, CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))

      #plot leaflet output
      output$myMap <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet() %>%
          addTiles() %>%
          addPolygons(data = selected)
      })    #END TOP LEAFLET OUTPUT
    }) #END OBSERVE EVENT 
  } #END SERVER
) #END SHINYAPP
```

Running this code as is works fine--the map updates with whichever country the user selects from the dropdown menu.

The problem occurs when I try to change the projection of the `selected` polygon within the Shiny observeEvent. The ultimate goal is to be able place the country level polygon over a regional-level polygon with the `rgeos` function `over` and update the map with regions rather than countries. I have achieved this within Shiny to create a perfectly functional app. But when I try to use that same exact code within this app, no dice. I've narrowed the problem down to the following lines of code (which are commented out above):

```
selected <- spTransform(selected, CRS("+proj=moll +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"))
selected <- gBuffer(selected, width = -.2)
selected <- spTransform(selected, CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))
```

When I uncomment those lines of code, the app breaks and gives me the following error:

> Warning: Error in [[: subscript out of bounds Stack trace (innermost
>   first):
>       74: slot
>       73: .spTransform_Polygons
>       72: spTransform
>       71: spTransform
>       70: spTransform
>       69: spTransform
>       68: observeEventHandler [#19]
>        4: 
>        3: do.call
>        2: print.shiny.appobj
>        1:  ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer

When I take the code out of Shiny and run it with a country string in place of `input$location`, it works perfectly fine. And again, I've gotten the same exact code to run in a different app with a click event. But the projection change breaks this one.

Does anyone have any insight why this `spTransform` breaks my Shiny app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just add an `if` statement to your code to filter the first automatic selection when the app starts: `""`.

**Note 1**: I selected a bigger `width` option in the `gBuffer` function to see how it changed!

```
#observe click event; zooms to administrative units for the country that is clicked on

observeEvent(input$location, {

      #subset countries shapefile by dropdown selection country

      selected <- countries[countries@data$sovereignt == input$location,]

      if(input$location != "") {

        selected <- spTransform(selected, CRS("+proj=moll +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"))
        selected <- gBuffer(selected, width = -100000)
        selected <- spTransform(selected, CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))

      }

      #plot leaflet output
      output$myMap <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet() %>%
          addTiles() %>%
          addPolygons(data = selected)

      })    #END TOP LEAFLET OUTPUT

    })
```

If you want that when the app start all the countries have the `gBuffer` effect applied you can use this code:

```
#observe click event; zooms to administrative units for the country that is clicked on
observeEvent(input$location, {

  #subset countries shapefile by dropdown selection country

  if(input$location == "" ) {

    selected <- countries

  } else {

    selected <- countries[countries@data$sovereignt == input$location,]

  }

  selected <- spTransform(selected, CRS("+proj=moll +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"))
  selected <- gBuffer(selected, width = -10000)
  selected <- spTransform(selected, CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))

  #plot leaflet output
  output$myMap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addPolygons(data = selected)

  })    #END TOP LEAFLET OUTPUT

}) #END OBSERVE EVENT
```

**Note 2:** At the begining you don't need to transform your spatial object because it has the projection you desired from the `ctry_hif.prj` file. See below:

```
#pull in full rock country shapefile, set WGS84 CRS
countries <- readOGR(dsn = "D:/NaturalEarth/HIF", layer = "ctry_hif", stringsAsFactors = F, encoding = "UTF-8")

proj4string(countries)

# Output:
[1] "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"

# countries <- spTransform(countries, CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")) # You don't need this
```

Comment: THANK YOU! Any idea why this works? It's the most bizarre thing because it works outside of a conditional statement in a different app. And thanks for the additional notes as well. Projection and buffer width were two fields I was playing around with to try to troubleshoot my problem, so they were relics of troubleshooting. But it's always nice to trim down code!

Comment: You are welcome! I think the main problem was in this line of code: `countries[countries@data$sovereignt == input$location,]` because the default `input$location` when your app started was this `""` (see your `selectInput` default selection: `selected = ""`). If you query your spatial object like this: `countries[countries@data$sovereignt == "",]` you get `0` features. And then you wanted to apply a transformation to a `0` feature spatial object and son on.